# d3 Text color inside graph

Tags: css, d3.js

I am trying to control the color of a text inside a graph rendered by `d3`:

Here is what I tried so far, in the bottom of my js code that creates the graph:

```
    d3.select('#gender_divide svg')
        .datum(datum)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr('width', 400)
        .attr('height', 400)
        .attr("fill","white")
        .attr('stroke', 'white')
        .call(chart);
```

This results in a white stroke around the text, but the text itself stays black, as you can see:

[image: Graph with black text with a white stroke]

Do you know how to change the text style inside the graph?

#### update the complete code:

```
 <div id="gender_divide"><svg style="width:350px;height:350px; body { color: white;}">  </svg></div>

<script>  
    data_gender_divide=[{"values": [{"value": 6.473124955585393, "label": "unknown"}, {"value": 71.34687526882524, "label": "men"}, {"value": 22.17999977558936, "label": "women"}], "key": "Serie 1"}];

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.pieChart();
        chart.margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 20, left: 60});
        var datum = data_gender_divide[0].values;

        chart.tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) {
                    var x = String(key);
                    var y =  String(y)  + ' %';

                    tooltip_str = '<center><b>'+x+'</b></center>' + y;
                    return tooltip_str;
                });

            chart.showLegend(false);
            chart.showLabels(true);

        chart.donut(false);

        chart
            .x(function(d) { return d.label })
            .y(function(d) { return d.value });
        chart.width(350);
        chart.height(350);

        d3.select('#gender_divide svg')
            .datum(datum)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .attr('width', 400)
            .attr('height', 400)
            .call(chart);
    });
</script>
```

Here is a working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/oz123/QyrwC/8/

Comment: You should use `.style("fill", "white")` instead of stroke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. The first is relatively simple, the second is more subtle.

1. In order to control the color of the text, you need to explicitly use `d3` to select the `<text>` elements you want to change. You need to do something like this:

   ```
   d3.selectAll("#gender_divide text").attr("fill", "white");
   ```
2. You're on the right track in that your code tries to set the `.attr("fill", "white")`, which is a valid way to change the fill color of a `<text>` element. However, NVD3 is automatically setting the `style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0)"` for your `<text>` elements, which is overwriting the `fill` you set. So, instead of setting `.attr("fill", "white")`, set the fill property of the style like this:

   ```
   d3.selectAll("#gender_divide text").style("fill", "white");
   ```

   Then NVD3 will not overwrite your fill, and your `<text>` will show up as white.

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/d2GcC/).

Comment: your answer is really not clear to me. I am not a js developer. I tried replacing  `.attr("fill","white")` with your suggestion, but it does not work .

Comment: The color of the text is defined by `fill`, but `fill` is a style property of `<text>`, not an attribute. Thus you set it as `d3.select("text").style("fill", "white")`. Try adding that command separately (after your previous command), and see if it works.

Comment: `d3.select("text").style("fill", "white")` still does not work.

Comment: Try `d3.selectAll("text").style("fill", "white")`. That should change all your text to white, instead of just the first element. If that doesn't work, please post a larger code sample.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comment above to Manoj, `selectAll` has an undesired effect that it changes all the graphs in the page.

Comment: Okay, looking at your code it seems to me `d3.selectAll("#gender_divide text").style("fill", "white")` should work.

Comment: I updated my answer and linked to version of your fiddle that seems to work.

Comment: Not true @mdml, if you look again, you'll see that there is a category listed there for "Presentation Attributes", under which can be found "fill".

Comment: @jshanley: yet that fails to change the fill. Is that a D3 controlled feature, then?

Comment: The problem in this case is that the nvd3 library that he is using overwrites the `style` property. So when you set the fill attribute, you are being overridden by the style that was set automatically. It basically looks like this: `<text fill="white" style="fill: rgb(0,0,0)">some text</text>`

Comment: @jshanley: thanks, didn't know that! I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe someday nvd3 will be properly documented ;)

Comment: @Oz123: please see my updated answer, jshanley made an important comment that I now address.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/QyrwC/1/)** here

**D3.Js**

```
 d3.selectAll("text").style("fill","red");
```

Comment: `selectAll` is quite cool, it works, but I have multiple graphs on this page. And some of them are stiil need to have black text.

Comment: add class name for those text ,then use d3.select(".selcted").style("fill",red);

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below to your JS:

`d3.select('#gender_divide text').attr("fill","white")`

The text within `text` elements can be colored using fill instead of stroke (which provides an outline). In your code, you arent implicitly selecting the `text` elements, merely the parent SVG.
An alternative would be to add the below to your CSS:

```
#gender_divide text{
   fill:white;
}
```